# Javascript global variable not staying changed outside callback function

Tags: javascript, function, cordova, callback, global-variables

```
var IAP_loaded = false; // Global Scope

var IAP_onReady = function(){
     storekit.load(IAP_list, function (products, invalidIds) {
            IAP_loaded = true;
            console.log("1] -- IAP Loaded: "+IAP_loaded); // Outputs true
     });
     console.log("2] -- IAP Loaded: "+IAP_loaded); // Outputs false
     IAP_loaded = true;
     console.log("3] -- IAP Loaded: "+IAP_loaded); // Outputs true
};

console.log("4] -- IAP Loaded: "+IAP_loaded); // Outputs false
```

For some my global variables aren't staying modified outside the function itself...
I created a completely separate function and changed a global variable and it works fine. This just mind baffles me. Any thoughts?

PS. This is a Phonegap 3.0 project and the callback function is from IAP plugin. Found here https://github.com/j3k0/PhoneGap-InAppPurchase-iOS

storekit.load is Asynchronous! Thanks for narrowing it.

`2] -- IAP Loaded: false
3] -- IAP Loaded: true
4] -- IAP Loaded: false
1] -- IAP Loaded: true`

I get back the response in that order. But it is not Ajax. It's through Objective C, the javascript just handles the responses so it's editable through javascript

Comment: If `storekit.load` is an AJAX call, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: storekit.load is Asynchronous! Thanks for narrowing it.

`2] -- IAP Loaded: false
3] -- IAP Loaded: true
4] -- IAP Loaded: false
1] -- IAP Loaded: true`

I get back the response in that order. But it is not Ajax. It's through Objective C, the javascript just handles the responses so it's editable through javascript

Comment: Right, but the same concepts apply. Understand the solution, not the language.

Comment: Where does IAP_onReady get called? It looks like this block of code runs *after* it is called, in which case you would be setting `IAP_loaded` to false again and the output you see would be correct.

Comment: Use `"use strict"` and you will have thrown error, this will help you to identify how to fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested IAP (in app purchase) works similar to Ajax. In fact most of phonegap plugins follow the same pattern.

First lets see how plugins works
- A call from JS is sent to Obj C file
- While Obj C is doing desired calculations other JS code and run simultaneously
- After Obj C has completed its calculations the output is sent back to JS via callback

Now lets try to see the code you have provided

```
var IAP_loaded = false; // Global Scope

var IAP_onReady = function(){
     storekit.load(IAP_list, function (products, invalidIds) {
            IAP_loaded = true;
            console.log("1] -- IAP Loaded: "+IAP_loaded); // Outputs true
     });
     console.log("2] -- IAP Loaded: "+IAP_loaded); // Outputs false
     IAP_loaded = true;
     console.log("3] -- IAP Loaded: "+IAP_loaded); // Outputs true
};

console.log("4] -- IAP Loaded: "+IAP_loaded); // Outputs false
```

Note - I'm referring to console.log as logs below

Now javascript runs the file is this order

You must be calling 'IAP_onReady' from somewhere, hence

- log 4 is printed instantly as it is a non-asyn code with output of 'IAP_loaded' as false. You have initiallized 'IAP_loaded' as false

> 4] -- IAP Loaded: false

- log 2 is printed instantly as it is a non-asyn code with output of var as false, as still 'IAP_loaded' hasn't been modified yet

> 2] -- IAP Loaded: false

- log 3 is printed instantly as it is a non-asyn code, but you have changed the value of 'IAP_loaded' manually to true

> 3] -- IAP Loaded: true

- Now after the execution of 'storekit.load' has completed log 1 is printed, and as here value of 'IAP_loaded' manually to true

> 1] -- IAP Loaded: true

Please try to provide us the complete code, as how the function is called etc.

Answer (score 0):

As with any async code, `IAP_loaded` is indeed changed to true but not before the code at the bottom executes. To check this, add this test at the bottom after 4:

```
(function check_IAP(){
    console.log("5] -- IAP Loaded: "+IAP_loaded);
    if (!IAP_loaded) {
        setTimeout(check_IAP,500);
    }
)();
```